# Overlay everything outside of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found what I was looking for the other day but cannot find it again.

I have a Div with position:aboslute and I'm looking to have a CSS overlay of everything besides that Div.

And if you click that overlay that goes away.

Please help!

Comment: try using bootstrap.

Comment: Your question is so vague, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have a div on the page. Everything beside that div has an opacity. When you click outside the div, opacity back to normal.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want done? or have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>

body {position:relative;}
#overlay  {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; 
height:100%; z-index:1000; background:#000; }
#modal {z-index:1001; position:absolute;}

$(document).on('click', '#overlay', function(){ 
$('#overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: I love you man. thanks robin. Small typo with id and class mixed up but you saved my life. thanks brotha. At work right now working on front end ish. feel me your the best baby thanks again.

Comment: Ah Thanks, have edited the answer.